# How do I use an Adobe Illustrator Die-Cut File as a template in Adobe InDesign?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, packaging

so my manufacturer was nice enough to give me die-lines in illustrator, but i want to use them as cutmarks/die-lines in InDesign, mainly to keep learning InDesign.  I imagine there's a pretty simple way to do this?  Would love someone to point the way.  Thank you!

Comment: I found the answer here: http://ellephillips.com/blog/tutorial-resize-packaging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `File > Place` to place your Illustrator file into InDesign.

Be certain you place the file at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Open the dieline file in illustrator and make sure the dieline is set a spot colour with overprints turned on (I usually rename the spot colour "Dieline").

Then save the file as an EPS or PDF. Then in illustrator create a page big enough to encompass the entire dieline plus bleeds, and import the dieline to its own layer in InDesign, move that layer to the top of your layers and start creating!

Make sure you import the dieline file at 100% and include it when you collect for output. Or if you are going to output to a PDF then you should be fine as long as you output with overprints left on. (use a PDF/X-1a standard or whatever your printer tells you to use)